# Check form HTML5 required attribute on submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a form but I'm stucked on this issue:

On my submit button I have this onclick statment:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault(); checkForm();"
```

and my checkForm function is like this:

```
function checkForm() {

    selectValue = $('#select').val();

    if(valorSelect == '') {

        alert('ERROR!');

    } else {

        $('#myForm').submit();

    }
}
```

That's ok. My problem is: There are other form elements (inputs) with the HTML5 attribute REQUIRED that are checked on form submit and, after the "preventDefault()" the pass unchecked on the $('#myForm').submit();

I had to validate this select separated because it uses the jquery plugin SELECTRIC and - in this case- REQUIRED attribute doesn't work.

How can I submit this form checking for the REQUIRED elements?

Comment: i think that this article could help you: http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the prevent default on the submit button, why not just call it when the form is actually submitted and the validation has been done?

```
onclick="checkForm();"

function checkForm() {

    selectValue = $('#select').val();

    if(valorSelect == '') {

        alert('ERROR!');

    } else {

        $('#myForm').submit(event);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```